# Document class article, maketitle with logo

Tags: graphics, formatting, titles

I want to modify the title section of the `article` class to look like something in the attached figure. Basically what I want is a kind of logo with flushed text (title, author, affiliation).

I tried playing little bit with `minipage`, `wrapfigure` but with no luck. Can you recommend a way of doing this?

[image]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Instead of redefining the `\maketitle` command, you can use `\parbox`es to produce the desired layout; something along these lines:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}  

\noindent\parbox[c]{.3\textwidth}{\includegraphics[width=.3\textwidth]{logo}}\hfill
\parbox[c]{.6\textwidth}{\raggedright%
  \sffamily {\LARGE Latest Developments in Evolutionary Biology--A New Perspective\par\bigskip}
  {John Doe\par\smallskip} 
{\footnotesize Theoretical Science Department, Nice University\par}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `demo` option for `graphicx` simply replaces actual figures with black rectangles; do *not* use that option in your actual document.

And, just for fun, an option using TikZ to replicate the logo:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{tikz}

\definecolor{bgcolor}{RGB}{247,242,222}
\definecolor{myred}{RGB}{152,31,32}

\newcommand\logo{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw=gray,line width=4pt,fill=bgcolor,rounded corners=3pt,minimum width=0.34\textwidth,align=center,inner sep=0pt,minimum height=3.3cm] (rect) 
{ \sffamily
  \parbox{.34\linewidth}{\color{myred}\footnotesize LECTURE \\ NOTES IN}%
  \parbox{.4\linewidth}{\color{myred}\Large\bfseries Science}
};
\draw[gray,line width=1pt] ([xshift=-8pt,yshift=-1.2cm]rect.north) -- +(0,-30pt);
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\begin{document}  

\noindent\parbox[c]{.38\textwidth}{\logo}\hfill
\parbox[c]{.6\textwidth}{\raggedright%
  \sffamily {\LARGE Latest Developments in Evolutionary Biology--A New Perspective\par\bigskip}
  {John Doe\par\smallskip} 
{\footnotesize Theoretical Science Department, Nice University\par}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: oh, please make the contents of the `\parbox` ragged right, and discourage hyphenation.

Comment: @barbarabeeton your wish is my command :-)